# What cable (or remote) shutter release for Fujifilm X100S?

Tags: fujifilm, shutter-release, fujifilm-x100

Does anyone know of any remote/cable shutter release that is compatible with the x100s?

I've been looking and I'm not sure if the RR-80 or 90 works.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your options are limited with the X100S.

For example, [this](http://www.fujirumors.com/remote-shutter-control-for-x-series-cameras/) post suggests that the X100S is not RR-80 compatible, and that your only option is a mechanical cable release.

There is some speculation on the web about X100S having the ability to release the shutter through a mic input.

[This](http://www.fujix-forum.com/index.php?/topic/12500-x100s-electronic-remote-shutter-release-thru-external-mic-inpus/?p=319831) user seems to believe that the [RR-90 Remote Release](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fujifilm-RR-90-Remote-Release/dp/B00DLQX7LO) does not have the correct USB size for the X100S, but has suggested an adapter for that USB port may work.

To be safe, I would purchase a mechanical shutter release. Something like [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Photo-Plus-Shutter-Release-Fujifilm/dp/B009647EAK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1437598507&sr=8-1&keywords=shutter+release+x100s).